# How to move a zip file to a new destination and then open it in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to move a zip file to a new destination and then open it in python 3. I have made following code, but it seems it does not work for zip file.

```
import os

source = "C:/Users/sa/Desktop/Pic_ - Im.zip"

destination = "C:/Users/sa/Pictures/pic"

os.rename(source, destination)
```

Comment: This doesn't open the zip file at all. what exactly is it you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

This will move the zip from one location to another and then extract its contents to a directory of your choosing (`other_dir`, in this instance)

```
import shutil
import zipfile
from contextlib import closing

def _unzip(archive, destination):
    with closing(zipfile.ZipFile(archive, 'r')) as zip_file:
        zip_file.extractall(destination)

SOURCE = "C:/Users/sa/Desktop/Pic_ - Im.zip"
DESTINATION = "C:/Users/sa/Pictures/pic"

shutil.move(SOURCE, DESTINATION)

_unzip(DESTINATION, other_dir)
```